# My 2 Threads are Producer&Consumer here.When i run the program it throws nosuchelementexception on removeFirst() call.Can someone explain

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

```
public class Processor {
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
public static final int LIMIT = 10;

public void producer() throws InterruptedException {
    Random random = new Random();
    synchronized (this) {
        while (true) {
            list.add(random.nextInt(100));
            if (list.size() > LIMIT) {
                wait();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void consumer() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    synchronized (this) {
        while (true) {
            int value = list.removeFirst();
            System.out.println("removed value is..." + value);
            if (list.size() < LIMIT) {
                notify();
            }

        }

    }
}
}
```

please explain me why i get no such element exception in the above code. producer and consumer are 2 threads and if i run am getting nosuchelementexception on removeFirst().

Comment: Can you share the code for starting the threads? If for some reason cunsumer enters synchronized block first you will get exactly that Exception

Comment: Why don't you use a `BlockingQueue` implementation? They are meant for such workloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The producer enters the synchronized block and adds 11 elements to the list. Since 11 is bigger than 10, it waits, and thus releases the lock, allowing the consumer to enter the synchronized block.

The consumer then starts an infinite loop inside a synchronized block, removing an element from the list at each iteration. It never calls `wait()` and it never breaks out of the while loop either. So it never releases the lock, and keeps iterating forever. After the 11th element read, the list is empty, hence the exception.

Comment: Reasonable answer except that you're assuming that the producer thread gets to run first.  But, the given code snippets don't show how the threads are started.  For all we know, the consumer thread may find the list empty on the very first iteration of its loop.  Of course, the outcome will be the same either way---a NoSuchElementException.